# Cygwin: bash.exe Application Error (0xc0000022)

Tags: windows-7, installation, cygwin, windows-7-x64

I have downloaded the cygwin setup executable.  When I run it, as adminstrator or not, I get the following message window:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000022). Click OK to
close the application.
```

Here is the list of "Unknown Package":

```
Package: Unknown package
    000-cygwin-post-install.sh exit code -1073741790
    autoconf.sh exit code -1073741790
    autoconf2.5.sh exit code -1073741790
    automake.sh exit code -1073741790
    automake1.10.sh exit code -1073741790
    automake1.11.sh exit code -1073741790
    automake1.4.sh exit code -1073741790
    automake1.5.sh exit code -1073741790
    automake1.6.sh exit code -1073741790
    automake1.7.sh exit code -1073741790
    automake1.8.sh exit code -1073741790
    automake1.9.sh exit code -1073741790
    base-files-mketc.sh exit code -1073741790
    base-files-profile.sh exit code -1073741790
    bash.sh exit code -1073741790
    bashdb.sh exit code -1073741790
    colordiff.sh exit code -1073741790
    colorgcc.sh exit code -1073741790
    coreutils.sh exit code -1073741790
    font-bh-lucidatypewriter-dpi75.sh exit code -1073741790
    fontconfig.sh exit code -1073741790
    gcc-g++.sh exit code -1073741790
    gcc-g77.sh exit code -1073741790
    gcc-java.sh exit code -1073741790
    gcc-mingw-core.sh exit code -1073741790
    gcc-mingw-g++.sh exit code -1073741790
    gcc-mingw-g77.sh exit code -1073741790
    gcc-mingw-java.sh exit code -1073741790
    gcc-mingw-objc.sh exit code -1073741790
    gcc.sh exit code -1073741790
    indent.sh exit code -1073741790
    man.sh exit code -1073741790
    terminfo.sh exit code -1073741790
    terminfo0.sh exit code -1073741790
    tidy.sh exit code -1073741790
    update-info-dir.sh exit code -1073741790
    xpdf.sh exit code -1073741790
```

As shown in the Postinstall script errors window.
I am installing on Windows 7, on a 64-bit computer.

**Edit 1:**
I checked the `cygwin` folder and it is marked as *read-only*.  This is a sticky bit and won't change.  I'm having my I.T. department investigate this issue.

How can I get rid of these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.  The company has an application SOPHOS which was interfering with the installation of Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your problem is, but when I get mysterious errors using Cygwin on 64-bit processors for the first time, my first thought is, "try [rebaseall](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Cygwin-Windows-7-gvim-woes-td3326781.html)."

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  My issue is that the Setup.exe is displaying "bash.exe - Application Error" window.  I don't have any dlls loaded yet. :-(